# How to unclass an instance list type into normal list type in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have the following class:

```
class Point:
    """ Given a list/vector create a class as single Point."""
    def __init__(self, coords, reference=None):
        self.coords = coords
        self.n = len(coords)
        self.reference = reference
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.coords)
```

That use to convert a list type of numbers into `Point` class instance.

```
In [64]: t1 = [10.715430492165567, 66.9063251413503]
In [65]: type(t1)
Out[65]: list

In [66]: t1p = Point(t1)  # Here we create the Point instance to t1
In [67]: type(t1p)
Out[67]: instance
```

What I want to do is to unclass `t1p` so that it becomes normal list again like `t1`. How can it be achieved?

Comment: Something wrong with `t1p=t1p.coords` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the method `__iter__` in your `Point` class:

```
class Point:
    [..]
    def __iter__(self):
        for coord in self.coords:
            yield coord
```

Then you can iterate over your Point object:

```
for x in t1p:
   print x
```

or just pass it to a list constructor

```
t1 = list(t1p)
```

Comment: `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.coords)` would be the same and more to the point.